# BeautifulSoup extract desired information in custome-made list from different html snippets

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Apologies in advance for such a long and basic question!

Given the following three `html` snippets which are part of a bigger part as follows:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <span _ngcontent-ont-c199="" class="font-weight-bold">
   <span _ngcontent-ont-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
    <span _ngcontent-ont-c199="" translate="">
     nro
    </span>
    4 A.
   </span>
   <!-- -->
   <span _ngcontent-ont-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
    6.12.1939
   </span>
   <!-- -->
  </span>
  <span _ngcontent-ont-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   , JR 10
  </span>
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <span _ngcontent-ont-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   :
   <span _ngcontent-ont-c199="" translate="">
    sivu
   </span>
   1
  </span>
 </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<html>
 <body>
  <span _ngcontent-evu-c199="" class="font-weight-bold">
   <!-- -->
   <span _ngcontent-evu-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
    1905
   </span>
   <!-- -->
  </span>
  <span _ngcontent-evu-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   , Aksel Paul
  </span>
  <!-- -->
  <span _ngcontent-evu-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   , Helsinki
  </span>
  <!-- -->
  <span _ngcontent-evu-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   :
   <span _ngcontent-evu-c199="" translate="">
    page
   </span>
   63
  </span>
 </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<html>
 <body>
  <span _ngcontent-ejj-c199="" class="badge badge-secondary ng-star-inserted">
   22
  </span>
  <span _ngcontent-dna-c199="" class="font-weight-bold">
   <span _ngcontent-dna-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
    <span _ngcontent-dna-c199="" translate="">
     nro
    </span>
    12 ZZ
   </span>
   <span _ngcontent-dna-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
    10.2016
   </span>
  </span>
  <span _ngcontent-ejj-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   , Arbetarförlaget Ab
  </span>
  <!-- -->
  <span _ngcontent-ejj-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   , Stockholm
  </span>
  <!-- -->
  <span _ngcontent-ejj-c199="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   :
   <span _ngcontent-ejj-c199="" translate="">
    sida
   </span>
   20
  </span>
 </body>
</html>
```

I would like to extract 6 different information (if available otherwise `None`) using a desired list which looks as follows:

```
desired_list = ["badge", "issue", "date", "publisher", "city", "page"]
```

So I have the following code (very inefficient using for loop):

```
desired_list = [None]*6 # initialize with [None, None, None, None, None, None]

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") # html_1, html_2, html_3

fwb = soup.find("span", class_="font-weight-bold")
issue_date = fwb.select("span.ng-star-inserted") # always a list of 2 elements: ['nro XX extension', 'DD.MM.YYYY']

for el in issue_date:
    element = el.text.split()
    if "nro" in element:
        desired_list[1] = " ".join(element) # handling issue: nro XX extension
    desired_list[2] = " ".join(element) # handling date: DD.MM.YYYY
badge = soup.find("span", class_="badge badge-secondary ng-star-inserted")
if badge: desired_list[0] = " ".join(badge.text.split()) # handling badge
```

Currently, I can only extract info for first three components in my `desired_list`, namely, `badge`, `issue`, `date`.

```
[None, 'nro 4 A.', '6.12.1939', None, None, None] # html_1
[None, None, '1905', None, None, None]            # html_2
['22', 'nro 12 ZZ', '10.2016', None, None, None]  # html_3
```

Whereas, my desired list for each `html` should looks like this:

```
[None, 'nro 4 A.', '6.12.1939', 'JR 10', None, 'sivu 1']                     # html_1
[None, None, '1905', 'Aksel Paul', 'Helsinki', 'page 63']                    # html_2
['22', 'nro 12 ZZ', '10.2016', 'Arbetarförlaget Ab', 'Stockholm', 'sida 20'] # html_3
```

And I don't know how to manipulate my code to retrieve all 6 fields given the aforementioned `html` snippets since their occurrences are very stochastic meaning that it can happen some information is missing. I really appreciate if someone can recommend me smarter and more efficient way of handling this.

I am aware of `soup.find_all("span", class_="ng-star-inserted")`. However, the problem is that `find_all` does not always return a list with length of 6 to enumerate!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just define a list of selectors corresponding to `desired_list`:

```py
selectors = [
    'span.badge.badge-secondary.ng-star-inserted',                                             #badge 
    'span.font-weight-bold span.ng-star-inserted:has(span[translate])',                        #issue 
    'span.font-weight-bold span.ng-star-inserted:last-child',                                  #date 
    'span.font-weight-bold ~ span.ng-star-inserted:-soup-contains(", ")',                      #publisher 
    'span.font-weight-bold ~ span.ng-star-inserted:-soup-contains(", ") + span.ng-star-inserted:-soup-contains(", ")', #city 
    'span.font-weight-bold ~ span.ng-star-inserted:-soup-contains(":")',                       #page 
]
```

and then

```py
desired_list = [None if s[0] is None else (
    s[0].get_text(' ', strip=True)[2:] if '-soup-contains' in s[1] 
    else s[0].get_text(' ', strip=True)
) for s in [(soup.select_one(sel), sel) for sel in selectors]]
```

should give you what you're looking for.

**Please note that** you *might* need to install and use [html5lib](https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/) parser (which can be a bit slower than lxml)

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib") # html_1, html_2, html_3
```

otherwise, [pseudoclasses](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/) like `:has` and `:-soup-contains` might raise errors or just return nothing. [Although, after installing html5lib, I noticed the selectors started working no matter which parser I used, including lxml...but I *did* need to install html5lib first]

Comment: Dude, I really appreciate your help! I did `pip install html5lib` in my conda workspace and it works with both `lxml` and `html5lib` parsers!

Answer (score 0):

I am not providing a solution but this is a clue. If you have a fixed structure and you don't have a way to distinguish between them. I suggest using [soup.find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to extract all items with class "ng-star-inserted" and then add them to the list in the desired order:

You can print them all like this:

```
    result = soup.find_all("span", "ng-star-inserted")
    for position, element in enumerate(result):
        print(el)
```

That will iterate over tuples of (position, element) in the list.
Then you need to figure out the location of the desired element, and put it into the appropriate position, for example:

```
    if position == you_need_to_figure_this_out:
        desired_list[desired_position] = element
```

If you can't map positions to elements, you need some heuristics to guess them.

"page" is easy `if el.text.isdigit()` then it is a "page"

"publisher" and "city" is harder, but it looks like there is always a "publisher", so the first string (without elements that are already processed in your question's code) will be a "publisher", and the second non-processed (if it exists) is a "city"

Comment: The problem is `find_all` does not return a list with length of 6 to enumerate! That is why I wrote a very high school ish approach using for loop to handle this!

Comment: I see, I would somehow guess the position for the "publisher", "city", "page"

page is easy ```if el.text.isdigit()``` then it is a page 

publisher and city is harder, but it looks like there is always a publisher, so the first string (without elements that are already processed in your question's code) will be a publisher, and second non-processed (if exists) is a city

Comment: Actually it is very stochastic in which there can happen any of these info be `None `. So city, publisher, or anything else! these are just three samples I provided to clarify what I aim for as `desired_list`